# UISearchController не размещен по центру ячейки вертикально ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, controller

я добавляю на UITableViewController UISearchController с помощью кода

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Введіть значення для пошуку"
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true

}
```

При этом UISearchController расположен впритык к верхнему краю ячейки в которой он находится. 
[image: скриншот]

Как выровнять его вертикально по центру в ячейке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас UISearchController примыкает к navigationItem. Если Вы хотите, чтобы он выравнивался относительно tableView, то используйте:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Comment: работает. немного по другому выглядит. в предыдущем варианте контроллер появлялся после дрэга вниз по экрану, а в новом варианте сразу виден. можно ли скрыть его как в предыдущем варианте?

Comment: Самый простой способ - спрятать: tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 22), animated: false)